# NVIDIA proprietary drivers, Ubuntu20 or 22 and black screen on the rebbot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, screen, reboot

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.6 or 22.04.3 in an new workstation with a NVIDIA  T400 4 GB GDDR6,. Ubuntu 22.04.3 recognized as   VGA compatible controller NVIDIA Corporation GA104GL[RTX A4000] (rev a1)  (command   lspci | grep -e VGA).

Every time that I allow the installation of additional drivers / NVIDIA proprietary drivers,  the  system fail to reboot  (black screen with blinking cursor).

In the installation process do not allow  third party software  installations, but if later  I allow any update of the drivers the system do not reboot (black screen with blinking cursor).

If I install the Ubuntu recommend drivers  or the ubuntu-drivers autoinstall  the system do not reboot again  (black screen with blinking cursor).

The only way to make it work is  not install any NVIDIA driver (no proprietary drivers in use)  and the Graphics instead of the NVIDIA Corporation usual in other machines  in this one it shows "  llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)".

Since this is a new machine I am trying to sort the problem before starting to upload it with software, since reinstalling Ubuntu is the only way that I know to sort the black screen   problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to download drivers manually ? `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` might be downloading wrong version of nvidia-driver for your system, instead of auto loading try:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
```

after getting a list of drivers, if it is avalaible try to download `nvidia-driver-525` using

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:525
```

or you can manually download drivers using `apt` (Which I recommend)

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
```

after reboot you can, verify installation with `nvidia-smi`.

You can see this [guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation) from ubuntu web site for more details.

Note that: I recommend downloading `nvidia-driver-525` since latest version `535` can be problematic for some systems

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. Previously I installed the 535 the recommended one, and that probably where the problem was.